# Rails collection_select with join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My tables:

[image]

Person belongs_to and 
Room has_many Person

My collection_select

```
 <%= collection_select(:inspection, :person_id, Person.involving(current_user), :id, :room_id) %>
```

If I'm not wrong, in HTML it will be represented as the following code:

```
<select name="post[person_id]">
        <option value="<%= person.id %>"><%= person.room_id %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

My point is that when a user submit the form I need send the Person Id value, but I need show on the drop down list the name of the rooms (in my example I showing the room.id) like that:

```
<select name="post[person_id]">
        <option value="<%= person.id %>"><%= room.name %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

How can I do that? 
As I see I think that I need join person table with room table? If it is the solution, how can I do that?

My person model:

```
scope :involving, -> (user) do
        where("persons.id = ?", user.id)
    end
```

My view

```
<%= form_for @inspection do |f| %>
      <label>Select</label>
      <%= collection_select(:inspection, :person_id, Person.involving(current_user), :id, :room.id) %>

      <%= f.submit  "Send" %>
```

I tried to make it as clear as I could.

Comment: In your collection select you're calling out `:room.id` as the method that will populate the name of your options. Have you tried changing that to `:room.name`?

Comment: actually is :room_id .. I updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `select` rather than `collection_select`. This method allows you finer grain control over what is used for id and name of each option.

In your case you'd want something like:

select(:inspection, :person_id, Person.involving(current_user).collect {|p| [ p.id, p.room.name ] }, { ...other method options... })

This allows you to specify the array of option id/name pairs. You get all the people involved using your scope, then iterate over those returning an array for each one found, where the first value in the array is the option value and the second is the displayed option text.

Check this [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) out for more details.